# Warm weather options in SE Asia (near Shanghai) in the winter

Tags: china, recommendations, weather-and-climate, beaches, shanghai

My wife and I have about 12 days of vacation before she starts a short internship in Shanghai in January.

We are both Americans and don't speak Chinese and this will be our first time in China. Before she starts her internship, we would like to enjoy a relaxing time in warm weather at a resort, near a beach.

Assuming that we are willing to go anywhere in East and South Asia leaving from and coming back to Shanghai during this time, what are some good options for a relaxing vacation in this area in December in relatively warm weather?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Travel.SE. Please, make your question less broad, or it will be closed as non-constructive.

Comment: Asia goes from Turkey and Russia to Japan and Russia, from Russia to Indonesia and Yemen and Sri Lanka. That's big. Are you really considering the whole continent and not some area closer to Shanghai? What do you mean by “good weather” (not too warm? not too cold? not too dry? not too wet? not too windy? …)? What relaxes you: a beach? a desert? all-night partying?

Comment: Thanks @VMAtm! I have just updated the OP to make it more specific (Shanghai, warm weather and beach/resort)

Comment: Also when you do specify all those things you still have to end up with a question which is good for other people besides yourself, if not it would be what Stack Exchange calls "too localized". This is why asking recommendation questions on Stack Exchange is difficult and discouraged.

Comment: Do you have a budget? You say you are 'willing to go anywhere'.

Comment: well he does say 'near' Shanghai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of South-East Asia will fit your description of the destination you want, including Malaysia, Singapore, Indonesia (these more so, since they are near the equator); and to a lesser extent Cambodia, Thailand, and Vietnam. You could also probably fly to Australia / New Zealand for similar fares enjoy *their* summer season.

November to March is roughly the time when many places near the equator in SE Asia have their rainy season, though this is highly variable. Take a look at what the weather is now - if it's already raining there, it will probably continue. Otherwise pick any destination in SE Asia you get the cheapest flights to!